# How can I get my third screen (laptop + two monitors) running on w/ nvidia drivers?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, twinview

I've got a laptop with GeForce GTX 560M and I'm using the nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 11.10 to support the a second monitor with twinview, which works fine.

When I run nvidia-settings, and connect my third monitor (counting the laptop display), nvidia-settings freezes indefinitely if I select to use it as twinview, too.  If I choose to display it as a separate X Screen, save the settings, and restart, that setting is never applied.  Here is the Xorg.conf created by nvidia on save:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 285.05.09  (buildd@allspice)  Wed Nov 16 15:25:12 UTC 2011

# commented out by update-manager, HAL is now used and auto-detects devices
# Keyboard settings are now read from /etc/default/console-setup
#Section "InputDevice"
#
#    # generated from default
#    Identifier     "Mouse0"
#    Driver         "mouse"
#    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
#    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
#    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
#    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
#EndSection
# commented out by update-manager, HAL is now used and auto-detects devices
# Keyboard settings are now read from /etc/default/console-setup
#Section "InputDevice"
#
#    # generated from default
#    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
#    Driver         "kbd"
#EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"

    # Keyboard settings are now read from /etc/default/console-setup
    #    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    # commented out by update-manager, HAL is now used and auto-detects devices
    # Keyboard settings are now read from /etc/default/console-setup
    #    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "0"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "1"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
    # commented out by update-manager, HAL is now used and auto-detects devices
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LEN"
    HorizSync       56.5 - 67.8
    VertRefresh     40.0 - 60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SyncMaster"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 560M"
    Option         "NoLogo" "True"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 560M"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"

    # Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DFP-2: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1920x1080 +0+0, DFP-2: 1680x1050 +1920+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080 +0+0, DFP-2: NULL"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-2: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1680x1050 +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1680x1050_60 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```

I'm not very handy with X config.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: GT 525M could be an Optimus model. Please [paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com) `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and mention your model name.

Answer (score 3):

More than 2 monitors isn't well supported by the GUI tools, in my experience. It's possible to configure the third monitor manually in xorg.conf, but there won't be any nifty plug-n-play behavior. You'll need an additional Device, Screen, and Monitor section to enable the third monitor, then add the Screen to the ServerLayout section. Here's my working quad-screen `xorg.conf` as an example:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen1" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen2" LeftOf "Screen1"
    Screen      2  "Screen3" LeftOf "Screen2"
    Screen      3  "Screen4" LeftOf "Screen3"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Samsung"
    ModelName      "Samsung ??"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 60.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SyncMaster"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor3"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SyncMaster"
        HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor4"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "WestingHouse"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    #BoardName      "GeForce 8800 GTS"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device3"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    #BoardName      "GeForce 9500 GT"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen         0 
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device4"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    #BoardName      "GeForce 9500 GT"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen         1 
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen3"
    Device         "Device3"
    Monitor        "Monitor3"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen4"
    Device         "Device4"
    Monitor        "Monitor4"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see any third monitor in Your xorg.conf file, maybe try to add it? 
(before doing anything copy Your xorg.conf file

```
sudo cp xorg.conf xorg.conf.old
```

)

paste this:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SyncMaster"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device0"  #or "Device1" depends to which is monitor connected
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1920x1080 +0+0, DFP-2: 1680x1050 +1920+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080 +0+0, DFP-2: NULL"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

and change Your server layout section:

```
Section "ServerLayout"

    # Keyboard settings are now read from /etc/default/console-setup
    #    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    # commented out by update-manager, HAL is now used and auto-detects devices
    # Keyboard settings are now read from /etc/default/console-setup
    #    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "0"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "1"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"  #only this line is edited
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
    # commented out by update-manager, HAL is now used and auto-detects devices
EndSection
```

Remember where Your xorg.conf file is, and if somethong goes wrong after reboot replace the edited with the old one. 
(

```
sudo mv xorg.conf.old xorg.conf
```

)